# Which is the best way to perform pagination on SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, pagination

I have a database with more than **2 million** records and I need to perform a pagination to show on my web application, which must have 10 records per page in a `DataGrid`.

I already tryied to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, but this way will select all the 2 million records and then get only 10 records. I also tryied to use `TOP 10`, but I would have to save the first and last id to control the pages. And I've read that using `DataAdapter.Fill()` will select all the content and then get the 10 records that I need.

Which is the best way? Should I use `DataAdapter.Fill()`? Or use the SQL Server's function `ROW_NUMBER()`? Or try to use `TOP 10`?

Comment: see this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/12/15/sql-server-server-side-paging-in-sql-server-2011-a-better-alternative/

Comment: Just read this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-vb It's a very complete tutorial (VB.NET but that doesn't matter in this case).

Comment: @Guilherme are you *really* still using sql-server-2000? (tags) if so, that will limit your options quite a bit.

Comment: He's using SQL 2008 (which he referred to as 2010), @Soner edited his question and added the wrong tag

Comment: I once have to use TOP option because I was using Sql-Server 2000. Its performance isn't good but you can try.

'SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT TOP pageSize *
 FROM 
 (SELECT TOP limit *
  FROM table ORDER BY orderByColumn ASC) 
 AS t1 ORDER BY orderByColumn DESC ) 
 AS t2 ORDER BY orderByColumn ASC;
 
 where limit equals pageSize * currentPage'

Comment: @AntonioBakula Unfortunally, I'm using SqlServer 2008. So, I need to use something different to work.

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh, it was my mistake. I put the wrong tag and text.

Comment: @calamar888 I don't think it's a good way to do, because as the number of pages increases, my select will be slower. And, in my case, it should be something fast and precise.

Comment: @Guilherme Oliveira: *any* method will be slower on later pages because it's simply more work for the DB to compute those - after all, to determine the exact row number of a row it generally needs to at least uniquely identify all rows before it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_tblTest_SelectSpecificRecordsWithCTE]
    @FromRow int = 1000000,
    @PgSize int = 10
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH RecordsRN AS
    (
        select ID, colValue, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by colvalue) as Num from tblTest
    )
    SELECT ID Value, colValue Text FROM RecordsRN WHERE Num between @FromRow AND (@FromRow+@PgSize-1)
END
```

that is the query i am using for paging. use it and u will get ur desired 10 records in 4-5 seconds. i am getting 10 records in 3 seconds and total records in my db are 10 million, dont use top 10 it will only bring same 10 records everytime. in my case i am maintaining page size and starting row number (@FromRow) in the session and i pass these two values to the below given stored procedure and get the result.
Further more if you are using SQL 2012 you might want to use OFFSET and Fetch next 10 rows kind of thing. search on google about OFFSET keyword and you will see your desired result on top.

thanks

Comment: All answers are really nice, but your is more similar to what I did, and I still think that is the best way. Unfortunally, my SQL Server is the 2008, so I don't have the OFFSET statement to use. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and implement an static utility function (as `GetPaginatedSQL` in my code), that automatically wraps your original SQL query into a limited/paginated one.

This is the one I use:

```
namespace Persistence.Utils
{
    public class SQLUtils
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a paginated/limited query from a SELECT SQL.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startRow">Start row</param>
        /// <param name="numberOfRows">Number/quatity of rows to be expected</param>
        /// <param name="sql">Original SQL (without its ordering clause)</param>
        /// <param name="orderingClause">MANDATORY: ordering clause (including ORDER BY keywords)</param>
        /// <returns>Paginated SQL ready to be executed.</returns>
        /// <remarks>SELECT keyword of original SQL must be placed exactly at the beginning of the SQL.</remarks>
        public static string GetPaginatedSQL(int startRow, int numberOfRows, string sql, string orderingClause)
        {
            // Ordering clause is mandatory!
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderingClause))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("orderingClause");

            // numberOfRows here is checked of disable building paginated/limited query
            // in case is not greater than 0. In this case we simply return the
            // query with its ordering clause appended to it. 
            // If ordering is not spe
            if (numberOfRows <= 0)
            {
                return String.Format("{0} {1}", sql, orderingClause);
            }
            // Extract the SELECT from the beginning.
            String partialSQL = sql.Remove(0, "SELECT ".Length);

            // Build the limited query...
            return String.Format(
                "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ({0}) AS rn, {1} ) AS SUB WHERE rn > {2} AND rn <= {3}",
                orderingClause,
                partialSQL,
                startRow.ToString(),
                (startRow + numberOfRows).ToString()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The function above might be improved, but is an initial implementation.

Then, in your DAOs, you should be just making something like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM MILLIONS_RECORDS_TABLE";
        String SQLOrderBy = "ORDER BY DATE ASC "; //GetOrderByClause(Object someInputParams);
        String limitedSQL = GetPaginatedSQL(0, 50, SQL, SQLOrderBy);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        cmd.CommandText = limitedSQL;

        // Add named parameters here to the command if needed...

        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        // Process the dataset...
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following pattern to (automatically) generate paged subqueries:

```
select top (@takeN) <your-column-list>
from (
    select qSub2.*, _row=row_number() over (order by SomeColumn Asc, SomethingElse Desc)
    from (
        select top (@takeN + @skipN) <your-column-list> 
        from ( 
            select <your-subquery-here>
        ) as qSub1 
        order by SomeColumn Asc, SomethingElse Desc
    ) as qSub2
) qSub3
where _row > @skipN
order by _row
```

Notes on this pattern:

- Sub a query conceptually Skips `@skipN` rows and then takes the next `@takeN` rows.
- If you don't care about the extra column `_row` in the result, you could replace `<your-column-list>` with `*`; I use the explicit column list because it allows me to subset the set of columns at runtime which can be useful e.g. to find only primay key columns and the like.
- Your `order by` clauses should be identical; sql server's optmizer is generally smart enough to understand that.  The duplication is a side-effect of the `top` clause used to truncate results; `top` isn't legal on unsorted subqueries.  And top is useful to help the query-optimizer understand this query is likely to return few rows.
- The reasons to use `@takeN` and  `@skipN` as opposed to page number + size based parameters are fairly minor.  Firstly, it's a little more flexible and a little simpler in the query, and secondly, it plays to sql servers strengths a little better: the DB isn't particularly brilliant about optimizing these kind of queries in the first place, and the hope is that an outer, simple top clause like this makes it trivial for the optimizer to understand the maximal number of rows possible.  In general, I try to avoid doing computation in sql I could do equally well in code since it tends to confuse the optimizer (though in the specific case of @pagecount*@pagesize experimentation has shown that it's not a huge problem)

Note that sql server 2012 supports a new [offset...fetch clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) for precisely this scenario which is much simpler.