# Bulk Insert into .CSV destination file using c# in SSIS script task

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I have a requirement for inserting a bunch of SQL Server tables data into .CSV files dynamically, I am using for each loop and Script task in control flow to write the data into CSV files, currently, I am reading row by row from source and writing it to the CSV file, which is taking much time, I am looking for Bulk insert option to write from SQL server to .CSV file destination. I did spend some time in researching about it but all I found was SqlBulkCopy class option, it works only if the destination is SQL Server table, Can you please help me with an approach that works for SQL server table as source and CSV file as a destination.

Comment: do you have access to use Export Wizard from Sql Server to Excel.. also have you looked up and examples for using SSIS bulk import / export another question or something to looks at is SSRS, how many rows are being returned.. you could create SSRS Report which gives you several export data options as well and you won't have to write your own export to excel code at all .. just some options to think about

Comment: Once you have the rows from the SQL table, did you try System.IO.File.WriteAllText() method to write all rows at once to a CSV file? - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hello Thanks for the reply,  I tried WriteAllText() but the performance is almost same, I am using OleDbdatareader.read() method, which is reading one row at a time from source table which is consuming much time, do you know by which method we can read rows in bulk and write them all at once using WriteAll Text.

Comment: Are you using an SqlDataReader to read the rows from the DB table? Depending on how many rows you are returning, you may be able get better performance by splitting into multiple threads and loading the data from the table using pagination. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339365/which-is-the-best-way-to-perform-pagination-on-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You can try to export SQL Server data to CSV by using the bcp Utility

[image]

```
bcp "query" queryout data_file -S server_name[\instance_name] -U login_id -P password -c
```

Example:

```
bcp "EXEC MyDatatabase.dbo.MyTable" queryout "C:\DataBCP.csv" –c –t , –S (local) –T
```

You can call bcp utility using System.Diagnostics.Process() in your C# code:

```
    Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    ProcessStartInfo pi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    pi.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe";
    pi.Arguments = "EXEC MyDatatabase.dbo.MyTable\" queryout \"C:\\DataBCP.csv\" –c –t , –S (local) –T";
    p.StartInfo = piOriginal;
    pi.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply, actually I am using OLEDB Connection class and passing SQL Server connection string as variable to it to connect to the database inside script task but ur using pi.Arguments = "EXEC MyDatatabase.dbo.MyTable\, I am thinking how this will work for my scenario.